# How do I update an array within an object from within state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

needing some help... how do I update the state to reflect a new schedule being added to a specific child (by id)?

I currently have a form that provides a new set of data that looks like this (with values from the form in the empty strings):

```
{
  date: '',
  parent: '',
  activity: ''
}
```

I've created this function below, and I'm passing it the `id` of the child, and the new schedule which looks like the one above... I'm stuck on this one:

```
addSched = (id, schedule) => {
  const newSched = this.state.children.map(child => {
    if (child.id !== id) return child;
    return {
      ...child,
      schedules: schedule
    };
  });
  this.setState({ children: newSched });
};
```

My current state looks like this:

```
state = {
  children: [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Bella',
    lastName: 'Laupama',
    schedules: [
      {
        id: 1,
        date: '25 December 2018',
        parent: 'Chris',
        activity: 'Christmas'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        date: '31 December 2018',
        parent: 'Laura',
        activity: 'New Years Eve'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Cara',
    lastName: 'Malane',
    schedules: [
      {
        id: 1,
        date: '25 December 2018',
        parent: 'Chris',
        activity: 'Christmas'
      } ...etc
```

And the component that has the form has the following:

```
export default class AddSched extends React.Component {
  state = {
   date: '',
   parent: '',
   activity: ''
  }

handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
 }

submitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.addSched(this.props.id, this.state)
  console.log('SUBMITTED:', this.state)
    this.setState({
    date: '',
    parent: '',
    activity: ''
    })
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to extend the current schedule for the child, rather than to replace it in the `addSched` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array spread operator to concatenate the existing array plus the new schedule:

```
schedules: [...child.schedules, schedule]
```

Here's the complete function with the change:

```
ddSched = (id, schedule) => {
  const newSched = this.state.children.map(child => {
    if (child.id !== id) return child;
    return {
      ...child,
      schedules: [...child.schedules, schedule]
    };
  });
  this.setState({ children: newSched });
};
```

Comment: So like this?

    addSched = (id, schedule) => {
    const newSched = this.state.children.map(child => {
      if (child.id !== id) return child
      return {
        ...child,
        schedules: [...child.schedules, schedule]
      }
    })
    this.setState({ children: newSched })
    }